# Show $(a \times b) \times (a \times c) = ( ( a \times b ) \cdot c ) a$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

> For three vectors $a,b,c\in\Bbb R^3$, show that
>   $$(a \times b) \times (a \times c) = ( ( a \times b ) \cdot c ) a$$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: What's the definition of $a\times b$.  And while we're at it what is the definition of $a\cdot b$.

Comment: @fleablood, why do you ask? These notations are well known.

Comment: @user159888: that is just scalar multiplication. Honestly guys, you can complain about the lack of effort here, but the notation is crystal clear.

Comment: @TonyK I read the questions as a hint to think from the definitions to a solution, as in the strategy of my answer.

Comment: @TonyK - seems clear that fleablood is employing the *Socratic method*

Comment: The OP *asked* how to do this.  The way to do this is to think about what the definitions are.

Comment: (Though technically all the OP did was copy imperatives...!)

Comment: @TheChaz2.0: I think it's fleablood who's playing Socrates here, not user159888.

Comment: @fleablood Is it clear now ?

Comment: "Is it clear now ?"  Is *what* clear now?  What's any different now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use the vector triple product formula,
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product

Let u=a×b
Then our question reduces to u×(a×c).
Opening up,
((a×b)•c)a - ((a×b)•a)c

The right one becomes 0. And your answer remains.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the left-hand side's $i$th component is $\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{jlm}a_lb_m\epsilon_{kno}a_nc_o$, while the right-hand side's $i$th component is $\epsilon_{jlm}a_lb_mc_ja_i$. To equate these, use $\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{kno}=\delta_{in}\delta_{jo}-\delta_{io}\delta_{jn}$.